# Azure DevOps release email notification with a list of files modified (commit logs)

Tags: azure, email, azure-devops, git-log, azure-repos

I want to send a list of files modified (commit logs) for current releases in the email along with the committer name in the Azure DevOps release pipeline.

I am not able to find a configuration for this requirement in Azure DevOps. If anybody has worked on this, please share your approach.

Comment: Hi nilesh1212, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, [Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops#supported-subscriptions) in Azure DevOps are pre-defined and doesn't support customized, so I am afraid that release notifications cannot meet your requirement.
[image]

In addition, as a workaround we can use the 3rd-party extension: [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask), which supports to configure body and add attachment.
[image]

Comment: This extension: [SendEmail](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) is free now.